# How do I get the direct (non transitive) dependencies of a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

Currently, when processing a [MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html), I'm using [getDependencyArtifacts](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getDependencyArtifacts()) to fetch the direct (non transitive) dependencies. However, this method is marked as deprecated. So, what am I supposed to use as a replacement ? I see there's the method [getDependencies](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getDependencies()), but it fetches transitive dependencies, and I don't see any way to filter direct dependencies.

Am I supposed to use [RepositorySystem](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystem.html), and its method [collectDependencies](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystem.html#collectDependencies-org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession-org.eclipse.aether.collection.CollectRequest-), and navigate the resulting graph, and get only the children of the root, which I guess would effectively be the direct dependencies ? Don't I have more direct, non deprecated approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on a quick search, there is an existing API called Aether.  Its documentation is not great.

The method in it is called: `getDependencies()` and it retrieves direct dependencies according to the javadoc.

https://maven.apache.org/resolver/maven-resolver-api/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/resolution/ArtifactDescriptorResult.html

There is an example on github:

```
public class GetDirectDependencies
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------" );
        System.out.println( GetDirectDependencies.class.getSimpleName() );

        RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

        RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

        Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:1.0.0.v20140518" );

        ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
        descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
        descriptorRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

        ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

        for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
        {
            System.out.println( dependency );
        }
    }

}
```

https://github.com/1984shekhar/fuse-examples-6.2/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/GetDirectDependencies.java

Comment: So you'd indeed go with `RepositorySystem`. Your solution sure looks better than getting the graph, I missed the `readArtifactDescriptor` as it didn't seem related to my problem at first. As for the documentation, Maven has a bunch of methods without any javadoc, so that's comparatively ok.